# Is there any way to implement integrated windows authentication in angular2?

Tags: active-directory, angular, windows-authentication

Is there any way/tutorial to implement integrated windows authentication in angular2?
I have searched for 4 hrs on google and there is no stackoverflow question yet.
Auth0 is no alternative, because its not free.

Comment: I don't think you need anything Angular-specific for this. How do you implement windows authentication without Angular (plain HTML + JS). AFAIK windows authentication is managed between server and browser. Nothing to do in custom client code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Much appreciated! I get it now. Windows Authentication credentials come from the browser and dont have to be handled manually to angular.